# Trigger on a table that uses Merge Insert Update as Incremental strategy

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

- Trigger under question is for Table which has ETL in ODI but user also has option to edit certain **columns **
  if they want to adjust them. This is done using **APEX**
- Trigger is used to change two columns : **Changed_by** and **Change_on**.
  Both indicating Changes done on APEX PAGE only.
- The issue comes when ODI load is run and is MERGE INSERT UPDATE , Trigger thinks its updating and changes the above two columns to "NULL" as its a manual update done by ODI and not on APEX.

Solution

- For each Editable Column, there should be a logic which checks NEW: <> :OLD, but as i have 15  columns need to write a lot of code.

**Are there others way to achieve this ?**

```
create or replace TRIGGER DW.TRG BEFORE
    UPDATE ON DW.TABLE
    REFERENCING
            NEW AS new
            OLD AS old
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF updating  THEN
        SELECT
            SYSDATE,
            v('APP_USER')
        INTO
            :new.changed_on_dt,
            :new.changed_by
        FROM
            dual;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Why would you need to write a bunch of code due to the number of columns? You have a single pair of CHANGED_ON_DT/CHANGED_BY columns to manipulate. You only need to compare :old and :new once and you're done.

Comment: don't use the "apex" tag. That is for a product by Salesforce that shares the name but is not related to Oracle APEX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if an apex session exists for the current database session and only execute when it is the case.

```
create or replace TRIGGER DW.TRG BEFORE
    UPDATE ON DW.TABLE
    REFERENCING
            NEW AS new
            OLD AS old
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF SYS_CONTEXT('APEX$SESSION','APP_SESSION') IS NOT NULL AND updating  THEN
    :new.changed_on_dt := SYSDATE;
    :new.changed_by := SYS_CONTEXT('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER');
  END IF;
END;
```

Notes

- avoid the `SELECT FROM DUAL`, you can just assign the values in the trigger.
- The "V" functions are pretty slow. For a while there have been sys_context settings that store the session and user data. Those are a lot faster than a function call to the "V" function.

Comment: hi koen ,thanks for the answer,  did you learn these through Oracle Apex Documentation itself ?

Comment: Probably not, I don't remember. I'm pretty active on forums and that is where I pick up things like this. The asktom session are also very useful

Answer (score 1):

You could make it so that it never overwrites a non-null value with a null one:

```
IF v('APP_USER') IS NOT NULL
THEN
  :new.changed_by := v('APP_USER');
  :new.changed_on_dt := SYSDATE;
END IF;
```